# Certificate failure using tsl with pgbouncer and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, containers, tls1.2, pgbouncer

Hi we are running into a problem with tls between PostgreSQL 11 and pgbouncer 1.9, both on the same host in different containers.
tls enabled and is working between client and pgbouncer and between pgbouncer and PostgreSQL. 
The problem is that client connet to pgbouncer with client key and certificate, and after auth pgbouncer pass the client with his/her username and password to postgreSQL and use its own pgbouncer certificate. Immediatly we got error because PostgreSQL checks the username and username in cert and they doesn't match. 
What is the right way of solving this issue? 
Is there a way to pass client certificate to pgbouncer and then to PostgreSQL?

Thank you

For now there is a mapping on postgres side like this
mymap pgbouncer clientuser

but this is not a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do in this case is *not* to use certificate authentication with PostgreSQL.

In a setup like yours, it is pgBouncer that verifies the authenticity of the incoming client connection using certificates. One this is done, you don't need any further verification.

So use the `trust` authentication for connections between pgBouncer and PostgreSQL, if that is a trusted network for you.